# How to make a function (templated or not) that accepts any iterator, but only iterators in c++

Tags: c++, function, iterator, parameter-passing

Is it possible to create a function that accepts any iterator(std::vector::iterator, etc.), but not anything else(int, bool, char, etc)? 
I'm trying to create a "bignum" class that has as much of the functionalities of built-in number types. I overloaded the operator+ to add two number types (bignum, int, double, float) together, and it worked perfectly, but I also want to implement another overload for the operator+ to work on iterators, where the effect of the operator+ on an iterator and my bignum will yield an iterator with an offset with the same amount as the value of the bignum (similar to adding an integer to an iterator). 
I searched everywhere on this topic, but all I find is something similar to finding out what type of iterator is being passed to a function, or is doing something similar to this:

```
template <typename Iterator>
Iterator function(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
//do something with begin and end
}
```

The problem with that is that the typename Iterator can be anything, including int, double, float, bignum, and it's not specifically getting an iterator, so I don't know how to do the one specifically for iterators other than doing it manually for all the containers. I also want this to work with all types of iterable iterators, and not only a specific iterator_tag (random_access_tag, etc.), but if that's not possible, I guess checking for all the iterator tags is easier to do.

Comment: Perhaps you can derefernce it in a `try` block, but overloading `*` will workaround that

Comment: That gives a compile-time error that disables it from working even with regular number types